# How can I reach celery procces and emit an event into dota2api

Tags: python, celery

**Basically, I am trying to make Celery script that holds a connection with dota2api and has reactions on some custom events. Script must *always* work.**

Here is **tasks.py**

```
from app.celery_ import app # Celery()
from person import dota2, client 
from config import username, password


@app.task()
def works():
    return True


@dota2.on('some_custom_event') # creates event using (gevent and gevent-eventemitter)
def profile_info_dota():
    with open('profile.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('emited')


@app.task()
def connection():
    client.login(username=username, password=password) 
    dota2.launch()
    client.run_forever()
```

**main.py:**

```
from time import sleep
from tasks import dota2, works, connection


connection.delay()
sleep(5)
dota2.emit('some_custom_event',)
result = works.delay().get()
print(result)
```

**The problem is that:**

I can't call any event

I can't call tasks after calling connect.delay()

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAsWS.png) of running celery and main.py (after calling works.delay().get() no event in Celery output and infinite loop because .get() is waiting)